# OOP and Tkinter - how to create widgets

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to create my own `Frame` in tkinter but I have some problems with OOP. Below is my code.

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk
from tkinter import *

class Listbox(tk.Listbox):
    def __init__(self, master, addValues = False, values = None, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Listbox.__init__(self, master, *args, **kwargs)
        
        # Tooltip
        self.lListOver = [-1, None, None]
        self.bind('<Motion>', lambda e: self.f_coord(e, l = self))
        self.bind('<Leave>', self.f_resetnListOver)
        
        if addValues:
            for value in values:
                self.insert(END, value)
        
        
    def f_coord(self, e, l):
        xEnrPos, yEnrPos = e.x, e.y
        idxOver = l.nearest(yEnrPos)
        lListCom = l.get(0, END)
        tLast = l.bbox(len(lListCom) - 1)
        if tLast is not None:
            yDownLast = tLast[1] + tLast[3]
            if yEnrPos > yDownLast:
                if self.lListOver[1] is not None:
                    self.f_resetnListOver(None)
                return None
        if idxOver != self.lListOver[0]:
            sX, sY = str(l.winfo_pointerx() + 15), str(l.winfo_pointery() + 15)
            if self.lListOver[1] is not None: self.lListOver[1].destroy()
            self.lListOver[1] = tk.Toplevel(l.master)
            self.lListOver[1].wm_geometry("+" + sX + "+" + sY)
            self.lListOver[1].wm_overrideredirect(True)
            tk.Label(self.lListOver[1], text = lListCom[idxOver], bg = "#217346", bd = 1, justify = tk.LEFT).pack(padx = 2, pady = 2)
            
            self.lListOver[0] = idxOver
            
        return None
    
    def f_resetnListOver(self, *d):
        if self.lListOver[1] is None: return None
        self.lListOver[0] = -1 
        self.lListOver[1].destroy()
        self.lListOver[1] = None
        self.lListOver[2] = None
        return None
    
        

class ListboxFrame(ttk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master, labelText, *args, **kwargs):
        ttk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
        
        # Listbox
        ttk.Label(self, text = labelText).grid(row = 0, column = 0, columnspan = 3)
        self.listbox = Listbox(self, height = 5, *args, **kwargs)
        self.listbox.grid(row = 1, column = 0, columnspan = 3, padx = 2, pady = 2)
        
        # Entry
        self.entry = ttk.Entry(self)
        self.entry.grid(row = 2, column = 0, padx = 2, pady = 2)
        
        # Buttons
        self.addButton = ttk.Button(self, text = "Add", width = 4, command = self.Add)
        self.addButton.grid(row = 2, column = 1, padx = 1, pady = 1)
        self.deleteButton = ttk.Button(self, text = "Delete", width = 6, command = self.Delete)
        self.deleteButton.grid(row = 2, column = 2, padx = 1, pady = 1)
        
        
    def Add(self):
        if self.entry.get() == "": return
        self.listbox.insert(END, self.entry.get())
        self.entry.delete(0, END)
        
    def Delete(self):
        for index in reversed(self.listbox.curselection()):
            self.listbox.delete(index)
        # listbox.config(height = listbox.size())
    
    
root = tk.Tk()
frame = ListboxFrame(root, "Listbox", addValues = True, values = ["Name", "Surname"], height = 10)
frame.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

What I'm trying to do here is to set the default height of my listbox in Frame to 5

`self.listbox = Listbox(self, height = 5, *args, **kwargs)`

but then when I want to create an instance of this Frame, I would like to pass another value of height

`frame = ListboxFrame(root, "Listbox", addValues = True, values = ["Name", "Surname"], height = 10)`

Here I'm also passing `addValues` and `values` arguments of my `Listbox` class. Unfortunately my code doesn't work and I got the error:

```
     33 
     34 root = tk.Tk()
---> 35 frame = ListboxFrame(root, "Listbox", addValues = True, values = ["Name", "Surname"], height = 10)
     36 frame.pack()
     37 root.mainloop()

<ipython-input-135-115c7d7ebda4> in __init__(self, master, labelText, *args, **kwargs)
      5         # Listbox
      6         ttk.Label(self, text = labelText).grid(row = 0, column = 0, columnspan = 3)
----> 7         self.listbox = Listbox(self, height = 5, *args, **kwargs)
      8         self.listbox.grid(row = 1, column = 0, columnspan = 3, padx = 2, pady = 2)
      9 

TypeError: type object got multiple values for keyword argument 'height'
```

I'm pretty new in OOP and Tkinter hence I hope you will be able to help me with this code to make it work.

Comment: In the error message, you can see how, in line 7, you pass `height=5` to the `Listbox`. But you also give it `**kwargs`, which contains the `height` argument passed to `ListboxFrame`. Try removing the `height=5` and see if that works.

Comment: Then it works but how can I put the default value of height for my Listbox? I woud like to set it to 5 (or any other value) by default so I can skip `height` argument in `frame = ListboxFrame(root, "Listbox", addValues = True, values = ["Name", "Surname"], height = 10)` if not necessary

Comment: You can set it yourself, if the value doesn't exist already. Something like `if not kwargs["height"]: kwargs["height"] = 5`.

Comment: Thanks,`if not kwargs["height"]` returns an key error but I replace it by `if not "height" in kwargs`

Comment: Of course. `["height"]` wouldn't be in `kwargs` if it wasn't in `kwargs`. I should have thought of that :-).